# How to get Django Admin to cache select options on inlines?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Using Django 1.11, Python 3.6

I'm having no luck whatsoever with this. I'm trying to optimise a slow Django Admin page which is making a lot of duplicate SQL queries due to a lot of `select` dropdowns and multiple inlines.

I've tried using the `cacheops` library and a Redis store, but nothing gets cached at all, even if I set *everything* to cache automatically with `'*.*': {'ops': 'all', 'timeout': 60*60},`. I'm assuming this may be because the Admin seems to bypass normal Django ORM objects.

Speaking of which, I tried just implementing a bespoke objects manager that caches using the `cachetools` library's TTLCache class:

```
from django.db import models
from cachetools import TTLCache, cached

cache = TTLCache(maxsize=100, ttl=3600)

class CacheManager(models.Manager):
    @cached(cache)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Caching get. args: %r. kwargs: %r" % (args, kwargs))
        return super(CacheManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached(cache)
    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Caching all. args: %r. kwargs: %r" % (args, kwargs))
        return super(CacheManager, self).all(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached(cache)
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Caching filter. args: %r. kwargs: %r" % (args, kwargs))
        return super(CacheManager, self).filter(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached(cache)
    def order_by(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Caching order_by. args: %r. kwargs: %r" % (args, kwargs))
        value = super(CacheManager, self).order_by(*args, **kwargs)
        print(value)
        return value

    @cached(cache)
    def first(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Caching first. args: %r. kwargs: %r" % (args, kwargs))
        return super(CacheManager, self).first(*args, **kwargs)
```

then my model class:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    objects = CacheManager()

    class Admin:
        manager = CacheManager()
```

This doesn't do anything either. At first I thought it was down to admin not using the bespoke objects manager, but I found a comment on StackOverflow that adding the Admin class with the manager is supposed to fix that - but it clearly doesn't in this case, because when loading an admin page that has a Role `select` I get this in the log:

2018-06-04 11:49:06,350 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.003) QUERY = 'SELECT [cms_role].[id], [cms_role].[date_added], [cms_role].[date_modified], [cms_role].[name] FROM [cms_role] ORDER BY [cms_role].[name] ASC' - PARAMS = (); args=()

** 20 more repeats of this skipped **

2018-06-04 11:49:07,572 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.002) QUERY = 'SELECT [cms_role].[id], [cms_role].[date_added], [cms_role].[date_modified], [cms_role].[name] FROM [cms_role] ORDER BY [cms_role].[name] ASC' - PARAMS = (); args=()

That's over a second of repeated SQL queries! How do I stop it from doing this??

Comment: I'm thinking with the CacheManager, this isn't working because it's actually caching the queryset which at that point probably hasn't been executed, so I'm not caching the results.

Comment: I've also confirmed that Cacheops *is* caching regular queries, i.e. outside of the Admin pages. This is only a problem for admin.

Comment: What is this `class Admin` in model? As far as I know it does nothing and admin is built another way.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic caching in admin is disabled in cacheops. This is explained [here](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/issues/287#issuecomment-394612143):

> Oh, caching is disabled in admin explicitely.
>
> This is historical decision, I wonder whether I should turn it off in next major version, but for now it stays this way. To cache in admin you need to overwrite `.get_queryset()` method and call `.cache()` on queryset yourself.

Not sure how querysets for various selects are formed though.